# Как посчитать кол-во узлов в двоичном дереве на js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, прошу помощи. Прохожу задачу на курсе по js. Застряла на [задании](https://ru.hexlet.io/challenges/js_introduction_to_oop_binary_tree_aggregation_exercise) .
Нужно посчитать кол-во узлов в двоичном дереве. При обходе дерева нужно использовать порядок слева-направо. Для реализации каждого из методов потребуется выполнить обход всех узлов дерева.

```js
class Node {

  constructor(key = null, child1 = null, child2 = null) {
    this.key = key;
    this.leftNode = child1;
    this.rightNode = child2;
  }
  getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }
  getLeft() {
    return this.leftNode;
  }
  getRight() {
    return this.rightNode;
  }

  preOrderTraverse() {
    //стоит организовать в одном месте обход дерева и использовать его во всех методах
  }
  getCount() {
    // Надо посчитать кол-во узлов
  }
}

const tree = new Node(9,
  new Node(4,
    new Node(8),
    new Node(6,
      new Node(3),
      new Node(7)
    )
  ),
  new Node(17,
    null,
    new Node(22,
      null,
      new Node(20)
    )
  )
);

//console.log('tree.getCount()', tree.getCount()); 
console.log(tree.getCount())
```

Comment: Это кому задание?

Comment: Обходить дерево для получения размера не обязательно. Можно просто добавить поле size. В конструкторе мы считаем size как child1.size + child2.size + 1. Если какой-то из детей null, то его размер 0. Таким образом операция получения размера будет O(1)

Comment: @Igor
Спасибо огромное, мне помогло

Comment: @neinso, спасибо, возьму на заметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Node {

  constructor(key = null, child1 = null, child2 = null) {
    this.key = key;
    this.leftNode = child1;
    this.rightNode = child2;
  }
  getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }
  getLeft() {
    return this.leftNode;
  }
  getRight() {
    return this.rightNode;
  }

  preOrderTraverse(cb) {
    cb(this);
    if (this.leftNode)
      this.leftNode.preOrderTraverse(cb);
    if (this.rightNode)
      this.rightNode.preOrderTraverse(cb);
  }
  getCount() {
    let count = 0;
    this.preOrderTraverse(() => count++);
    return count;
  }
}

const tree = new Node(9,
  new Node(4,
    new Node(8),
    new Node(6,
      new Node(3),
      new Node(7)
    )
  ),
  new Node(17,
    null,
    new Node(22,
      null,
      new Node(20)
    )
  )
);

console.log(tree.getCount())
```